# how can I generate message queue and binding keys dynamically with PK value in SpringBoot AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to implement a feature where users belonging to a specific group can post something within the group, and all members of the group will receive notifications.

To achieve this, I studied AMQP and RabbitMQ and now I want to apply it. as I understand, In AMQP, there is a message broker with components such as exchanges, queues, and bindings. When a producer creates a message, it is sent to an exchange, which can route the message directly to a queue based on message routing strategies or based on message headers and keys. Once the message is in the queue, it is delivered to consumers connected to that queue.

Now, considering the part I want to implement, I realized that a message queue for each group should be created when a group is formed, so that group-specific notifications can be delivered. However, when studying how to implement AMQP using `rabbitTemplate` and `rabbitListener` in Spring Boot, I found that I cannot dynamically set all queue names and binding key names; they seem to require predefined constant strings. I intended to use the group's generated primary key (PK) dynamically as part of the binding key and queue name to distinguish between groups. However, since I need to set the queue name with annotations or Spring Beans before the logic is executed, I'm not sure how to achieve dynamic configuration.

```java
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = , durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "#{rabbitmqNameProvider.buildQueueName}", type = "direct")
    ))
    public void consumeMessage()
```

This is the part I am concerned about. In another question, I heard that using "magic bean" allows setting names dynamically, but I couldn't find a way to pass the id for the dynamic configuration.

here's magic bean part

```java
@Component
public class RabbitmqNameProvider {

    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;
    @Autowired
    public RabbitmqNameProvider(ProjectRepository projectRepository) {
        this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public String buildQueueName(Long id) {
        String projectName = projectRepository.findTitleById(id);
        return "project."+projectName+".queue";
    }
}
```

actually I don't even sure that I can use @Transactional and @Autowired annotation in component like that.

```java
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

public void declareQueueForGroup(Group group) {
    String queueName = "group.queue." + group.getId();
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false);
    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
}
```

or do I have to implement another admin service or api for apply this like above??
there are so many thinkings and I cannot organize it well...

the key question is, how to implement the feature I described in the first part of the question.
thank you for reading my long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic understanding is incorrect; each user needs its own queue, not just one queue per user group.

You can use a fanout exchange to send a message to multiple queues.

You can add queues to the listener container at runtime.

See the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-queues

> Container can be initially configured to listen on zero queues. Queues can be added and removed at runtime. The `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` recycles (cancels and re-creates) all consumers when any pre-fetched messages have been processed. The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` creates/cancels individual consumer(s) for each queue without affecting consumers on other queues. See the Javadoc for the `addQueues`, `addQueueNames`, `removeQueues` and `removeQueueNames` methods.

Use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` to get a reference to the listener container(s).

Comment: Wow... Amazing.
I've encountered your name a lot while studying Spring and attending classes.
Thank you for answering my questions.
I need to study more.. So, if I understand correctly, should I create exchanges for each group (not sure if this is correct), and then use fanout to distribute messages to the queues (group members) under that exchange?

Comment: That is correct. A fan out exchange or each group and a queue for each user.

Comment: Thank you for your help !! I finally got it